# Given an instance of a behavior can I apply a message to it to create a new behavior

Tags: scala, akka, akka-typed

I have a scenario where I am handling a generic Behavior that needs some extra information when a message is received:

```
case class A(count: Int)

type MyBehavior[T] = Behavior[(A, T)]
```

The code to handle this extra information might be something like the following:

```
case class B(str: String)

def active(b: B): MyBehavior[B] = Behaviors.receiveMessage {
  case (a, b) =>
    active(b.copy(str = a.count.toString)
}
```

I then have a function to handle this Behavior generically. But given a reference to a behavior, I don't know how to apply a message to it to create a new behavior:

```
def f[T](a: A, behavior: MyBehavior[T])(implicit ct: ClassTag[T]): Behavior[T] =
    Behaviors.receiveMessage {
        case t: T =>
            val newBehavior: MyBehavior[T] = ???   // Can I pass a and t?
            f(a.copy(count = a.count + 1), newBehavior)
}
```

Is there a way for me to apply a message to a behavior to create a new behavior?

Comment: you should mention that you are using akka, your code looks like its self contained as it has zero external references or imports. Its very hard to follow without the context

Comment: @A-Developer-Has-No-Name That is what the tags are for. This one is labelled `akka` so you can't expect to understand it if you are not familiar with `akka`. You can filter out questions with that tag, just as I do for `apache-spark` which tends to have questions like this that assume knowledge of Spark.

Comment: @A-Developer-Has-No-Name if you follow on Akka trends you can recognize `Behavior` immediately as typed actors from Akka Typed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can spawn a new actor using `context` and send a message to if from your current actor. This way you can "prepend" some logic before action done by that actor.

```
Behaviors.setup { context =>

  def f[T](implicit ct: ClassTag[T]): Behavior[(A, T)] =
    Behaviors.receiveMessage {
      case (a: A, t: T) =>
        val newA = a.copy(count = a.count + 1)
        val newActor = context.spawn(f[T])
        newActor ! (newA, t)
    }
}
```

Important thing that is missing from your code - behavior is a *recipe* for an actor, but it is *not an actor on its own*. You have to instantiate it using `ActorSystem(behavior, actorSystemName)` (entry to whole system) or via `context.spawn(behavior)`. Without that you recursive calls will be just recursive calls, not sending a message from actor to a newly spawned actor.

Comment: Behavior.interpretMessage is not appropriate to use in this scenario?